# Android Source, Git/Repo and error: '.../.repo/repo/.git/clone.bundle' does not look like a v2 bundle file

Tags: android, macos, git, repository

I'm having problems updating my Android source tree on Mac OS X (10.7.3), x64 Intel. The code was installed per  [Downloading the Source Tree](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), and SE Android was applied per [How do I get the SE Android code?](http://selinuxproject.org/page/SEAndroid#How_do_I_get_the_SE_Android_code.3F).

According to [Version Control with Repo and Git](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html), I issued `repo sync`, which resulted in:

```
error: '.../.repo/repo/.git/clone.bundle' does not look like a v2 bundle file
```

I also tried to use `git pull`, which resulted in:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Both commands were executed from the root of the source tree.

Any ideas?

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too.

You might want to try getting the repo again and retrying.

```
$ curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

There could be problems with checksums, which is probably why pulling the latest repo helps.
Redo `repo init` and `repo sync`.